# Sonar plugin development: sensor/decorator constructor parameters

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

is there a list of valid parameters for Sensors and Decorators that I can get from Sonar?
I've seen a few get a `FileSystem` object or `ResourcePerspectives`. What exactly is the rule? Can I just put `MyCrazyClass` in the constructor and Sonar will figure it out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no list with valid parameters for Sensor/Decorator Constructors.

If your MyCrazyClass class implements the interface [BatchComponent](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/BatchComponent.java) Sonar will figure it out.

Since 5.2 [BatchSide](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/BatchSide.java).